# Convert a Pandas Dataframe in a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame in the following format

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1], 
                   [1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1],
                   [1, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5, 0],
                   [1, 5, 1, 3, 3, 6, 0],
                   [2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1],
                   [2, 7, 3, 2, 6, 8, 1],
                   [2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1]], 
                   columns=['person_id', 'object_id', 'col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4','label'])
```

In a more visual way, this is how the DataFrame looks. It has a `person_id` and an `object_id` column. Then some columns such as `col_x` and finally the `label`.

```
   person_id  object_id  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  label
0          1          2      4      5      7      8      1
1          1          3      1      3      4      6      1
2          1          4      1      2      6      5      0
3          1          5      1      3      3      6      0
4          2          6      3      5      1      3      1
5          2          7      3      2      6      8      1
6          2          1      3      1      0      4      1
```

I want to use a function from a library that needs the input in a specific format. In specific, I want to group by `person_id`, `object_id` and `label` and then create a list of lists with the `col_x` and a regular list with the `label`. Based on the example above, it will be

```
bags = [
[[4, 5, 7, 8],[1, 3, 4, 6]],
[[1, 2, 6, 5],[1, 3, 3, 6]],
[[3, 5, 1, 3],[3, 2, 6, 8],[3, 1, 0, 4]]
]

labels = [1,0,1]
```

What I do now is iterating in the pandas and create the two new lists dynamically. However, I know it's not wise and I am looking for a more pythonic and better approach in performance.

**My ugly solution**

```
bags = []
labels = []

uniquePeople = df['person_id'].unique()

predictors = ['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4']
for unp in uniquePeople:
    person = df[ (df['person_id'] == unp) && (df['label'] == 1) ][predictors].values
    label = 1
    if len(person) > 0:
        bags.append(person)
        labels.append(label)

    person = df[ (df['person_id'] == unp) && (df['label'] == 0) ][predictors].values
    label = 0
    if len(person) > 0:
        bags.append(paper)
        labels.append(label)
```

P.S. I did a heavy lifting in the code on the fly to make it proper for stackoverflow. In case you find something wrong there, don't bother. The aim is to find a better one, not to fix the ugly one :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function by both columns for `Series`:

```
predictors = ['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4']
s = (df.groupby(['person_id','label'], sort=False)[predictors]
       .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()))
print (s)
person_id  label
1          1                      [[4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 3, 4, 6]]
           0                      [[1, 2, 6, 5], [1, 3, 3, 6]]
2          1        [[3, 5, 1, 3], [3, 2, 6, 8], [3, 1, 0, 4]]
dtype: object
```

And then convert `Series` to lists:

```
bags = s.tolist()
print (bags)
[[[4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 3, 4, 6]], 
 [[1, 2, 6, 5], [1, 3, 3, 6]], 
 [[3, 5, 1, 3], [3, 2, 6, 8], [3, 1, 0, 4]]]
```

And second level of `MultiIndex` by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) too:

```
labels = s.index.get_level_values(1).tolist()
print (labels)
[1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Insanely improve in performance! Awesome! Always socked with what Pandas can achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
import pandas as pd

df = df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1], 
                   [1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1],
                   [1, 4, 1, 2, 6, 5, 0],
                   [1, 5, 1, 3, 3, 6, 0],
                   [2, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 1],
                   [2, 7, 3, 2, 6, 8, 1],
                   [2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1]], 
                   columns=['person_id', 'object_id', 'col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4','label']) # example dataframe


df['cols'] = df[['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4']].apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1) # create a new column with col_x as element of a list

tmp = df.groupby(['person_id', 'label'])[['cols']].agg(list) # group by and create list of lists

bags = tmp['cols'].tolist() # unpack
labels = tmp.index.droplevel(0)
```